# Re-exporting all members of a TypeScript namespace

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to re-export everything in a namespace from a new module. I've tried the following, which works to a degree:

```
// index.ts
import * as foo from 'foo';

function myFunction() {}

// Re-export everything in 'foo' along with myFunction
const thing = {
  ...foo,
  myFunction,
}
export = thing;
```

This results in a type declaration as follows:

```
import * as foo from 'foo';
declare function myFunction();
declare const thing: {
    Foo: typeof foo.Foo;
    Bar: typeof foo.Bar;
    myFunction: typeof myFunction;
};
export = thing;
```

But when I try to consume the types from the generated `d.ts` file, I get an error:

```
'Foo' refers to a value, but used as a type
```

I suppose this is because `Foo` and `Bar` as declared as members of an object. Is there a way to achieve this re-export of existing types in a new module?

Comment: Object spread, namespace imports, and export assignment are all very different. In fact, the error that you encountered is just the tip of the iceberg

Comment: Yes, I'm sort of learning that the hard way. It may be that the only working solution is just re-exporting each individual member of `foo` separately, which is what I was hoping to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
export * from 'foo';
export function myFunction() {}
```

Comment: This was one of the first ideas tried. Unfortunately, the other module I'm trying to re-export (which is a separate package in fact), uses `export = ` and therefore cannot be re-exported as `export *`.